# Using MapStruct Conditional Mapping to control whether to ignore a target property or not

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using mapStruct library, and I have this Mapper class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MenuLanguageMapper {

      MenuLanguageViewDTO toViewFromEntity(MenuLanguage entity);

      List<MenuLanguageViewDTO> toViewListFromEntityList(List<MenuLanguage> entityList);
}
```

both `MenuLanguage` and `MenulanguageViewDTO` both have a field called `id`, I would like to control whether I want to ignore it or not in the target, since in some of my MenuLanguageViewDTO's I want to include the 'id', rather than having to create completly new methods to do that, is that possible, I discovered conditional Mapping, but I cant seem to get it to work, mapStruct states that it supports Conditional Mapping now: [mapStruct Documentations](https://mapstruct.org/news/2021-07-18-mapstruct-1_5_0_Beta1-is-out/#conditional-mapping)

**edit-1:** added two classes, to clarify the issue that I am facing when going the path of creating two seperate mapper methods, one with Id and one without:

***MenuLanguageMapper.class:***

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MenuLanguageMapper {

      MenuLanguageViewDTO toViewFromEntity(MenuLanguage entity);

      List<MenuLanguageViewDTO> toViewListFromEntityList(List<MenuLanguage> entityList);
}
```

***MenuTranslationMapper.class:***

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { MenuLanguageMapper.class })
public interface MenuTranslationMapper {

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    MenuTranslationViewDTO toViewFromEntity(MenuTranslation entity);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    void toTranslationEntityFromUpdateDTO(MenuTranslationUpdateDTO updateDTO, @MappingTarget MenuTranslation menuTranslation);
}
```

Comment: How do you imagine the option to include/exclude `id`? Would it really be more useful than calling another method?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I did try the idea of having seperate methods, but the way I did it, it also affected the other Mappers who have an inverse relationship with it, as it could not differentiate between the two Mappers the one with Id and the other withoutId calling it umbegious.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following method:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MenuLanguageMapper {

    default MenuLanguageViewDTO toViewFromEntity(MenuLanguage entity, boolean ignoreId) {
        return ignoreId
            ? toViewFromEntityWithoutId(entity)
            : toViewFromEntityWithId(entity);
    }

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    MenuLanguageViewDTO toViewFromEntityWithoutId(MenuLanguage entity);

    MenuLanguageViewDTO toViewFromEntityWithId(MenuLanguage entity);
```

}

Or you can create a wrapper class that will inject `MenuLanguageMapper`, if you don't want to see the "internal" methods in the interface.

Comment: but, if there was another Mapper that has an inverse relationship with the MenyLanguageMapper, say MenuTranslationMapper which uses the "MenuLanguageMapper.class", wouldent this code cause ambagious error, since it cant differentiate between: "toViewFromEntityWithoutId" and "toViewFromEntityWithId".

Comment: I don't undesrtand what you mean by "inverse relationship". Please, could you clarify your thoughts?

Comment: @MaksomEliseev

I edited my question and include two mapper classes I have, as you can see, "MenuTranslationMapper" injects "MenuLanguageMapper" and implements it when mapping MenuTranslations. 
The first idea that came into my mind when I faced this dilema was to think the same way, but once I applied the code, the MenuTranslationMapper could not differentiate between the "toViewFromEntityWithoutId" and "toViewFromEntityWithId" returning that the methods are ambiguous.

If I can find a way to solve the issue of ambiguity and usage in other Mappers, then your code would possibly work.

Comment: @SpaceSloth, I think the best and easiest way would be to call a special method after mapping, in which the `id` will be deleted.